# How to print all keys and values from MongoDB?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, key

I have for instance following records in a collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f0224ad6f85ce027e000031"), "monday" : "7am" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f0224ad6f85ce027e00002e"), "tuesday" : "11.40am" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f0224ad6f85ce027e000025"), "wednestay" : "12am", 
                                                "thursday" : "1pm" }
```

In the controller I will grab all items and in the view I would like to print them in the shape:

```
monday 7am
tuesday 11.40am
wednesday 12am  thursday 1pm
```

My app is running on Rails. Exist any quick & elegant way to do it? Thanks!

**EDIT**
this works me:

```
records = collection.where('something' => variable)

records.each do |rec|
  puts rec._id
end
```

this not

```
records = collection.where('something' => variable)

records.each do |rec|
  rec.each do |k, v| #here is the error "undefined each"
    next if k == '_id' # skip the _id field
    puts "#{k} #{v}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically don't have to do anything. Just load all records, loop through them, and print.

```
records = collection.find()

records.each do |rec|
  rec.attributes.each do |k, v|
    next if k == '_id' # skip the _id field
    puts "#{k} #{v}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I still try your idea, but I am getting the error `undefined method `each' for #<ModelName:0x0000010165d720>` - in the DB table of course are the data. I am getting this error on the line `rec.each do |k, v|`

Comment: Just a note: I used instead `find()` method `where`

Comment: Apparently, it returned only one record instead of a collection. Revise your search criteria.

Comment: when I try loop only in the first loop a `puts` data, for example `puts rec._id`, so I will get around 20 items from DB table, so the variable `records` is a collection

Comment: How are you looping then, if `.each` is undefined?

Comment: Also, are you using raw driver, or something like Mongoid?

Comment: I updated my question. I try it in the controller (and my driver is Mongoid)

Comment: So, do you have defined fields in your model then? Like `field :monday`?

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it now.

Comment: No, because I don't know in advance, how many fields will be in the collection - and what.

Comment: @user984621: My pleasure. In return, could I ask you to fill your profile? It's much better to see a real person instead of anonymous user :-)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm using ruby `mongo` driver.  however getting the error `undefined method `attributes' for #<BSON::Document:0x162ba378> (NoMethodError)`  on the line `rec.attributes.each do |k, v|`

Comment: @user3206440: the `attributes` comes from mongoid, I think. And raw documents from the driver must have something else for this purpose.

Comment: if using `mongo` driver one can use `rec.keys.each do |k| ... ` instead of `rec.attributes.each do |k, v|` in the answer above

Comment: @user3206440 using keys seem to print only the keys but not the values, is there any fix?