# Ruby pretty print a BSON document?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, bson

I am using Ruby to print out a BSON document in MongoDB. This is done using a Ruby wrapper for MongoDB.

```
  client[:test].find().each do |doc|
    puts doc.to_json()
  end
```

The find method returns a BSON document. This can be [converted](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongodb/bson-ruby/BSON/JSON) to a string using the `to_json` method.

The output which looks like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5a64d2ce36ab1f1ea4b06228"},"admin":"1234","users":"12345","house":{"a":0,"b":0,"c":0},"room":{"a":0,"b":2,"c":1}}
```

The output is not very human readable. While I could possibly use some regex magic to format the above string to something more comprehensible, is there an easier way to format a BSON document nicely in a similar format as below:

```
_id: #
"admin": "1234"
"users": "12345"
"house":
  "a": 1
  "b": 2
```

I have tried the following [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705993/how-to-print-all-keys-and-values-from-mongodb) link. However, the answer yields a no method error for `attributes` and following the replacing that with `keys` following the comment only prints **keys**, not **values**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't used mongodb or BSON before, if we approach this from a JSON perspective you have a couple options. First, instead of calling `doc.to_json`, it looks like that uses a method `as_json` to get a hash representation, that it then turns into a string, so we'll use `doc.as_json` as a starting point instead.

```
doc = {"_id":{"$oid":"5a64d2ce36ab1f1ea4b06228"},"admin":"1234","users":"12345","house":{"a":0,"b":0,"c":0},"room":{"a":0,"b":2,"c":1}}
```

The first way is to use the [`PP`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) library which is a pretty printer for ruby:

```
require 'pp'
pp doc
# Outputs:
# {:_id=>{:$oid=>"5a64d2ce36ab1f1ea4b06228"},
#  :admin=>"1234",
#  :users=>"12345",
#  :house=>{:a=>0, :b=>0, :c=>0},
#  :room=>{:a=>0, :b=>2, :c=>1}}
```

which is close to what you want, the `pp` library has a way to define a customized output by defining a `#pretty_print(pp)` function in your class, that you can use to help get it the rest of the way.

The second option to look into is [`JSON.pretty_generate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate)

```
require 'json'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(doc)
# {
#   "_id": {
#     "$oid": "5a64d2ce36ab1f1ea4b06228"
#   },
#   "admin": "1234",
#   "users": "12345",
#   "house": {
#     "a": 0,
#     "b": 0,
#     "c": 0
#   },
#   "room": {
#     "a": 0,
#     "b": 2,
#     "c": 1
#   }
# }
```

Which is a bit closer to what you're wanting. With some post-processing you can get rid of those brackets and commas, if you want:

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(doc).delete('{},').gsub(/\n\s*\n/, "\n")
```

As for why switching from `attributes` to `keys` starts outputting only the `keys`, well `attributes` looks and sounds like it would be a hash, thus looping through you have 2 elements being passed to the block each time, and `keys` sounds like an array, so you only get the name of the attribute. As mentioned, I don't know mongo, but you would then need to somehow look up the attribute with the key named on your model to get it's value. For instance in ActiveRecord, you might use a `public_send(key)` if you weren't able to use its `attributes` method.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Awesome Print

Once you've converted BSON to a Ruby Hash, you have many options. One of them is using the [Awesome Print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) gem to pretty print your hash object with a variety of configurable options. For example:

```
require 'awesome_print'

hash = {:_id=>{:$oid=>"5a64d2ce36ab1f1ea4b06228"},
        :admin=>"1234",
        :users=>"12345",
        :house=>{:a=>0, :b=>0, :c=>0},
        :room=>{:a=>0, :b=>2, :c=>1}}
ap h, indent: 2, index: false
```

> ```
> {
>     :_id => {
>     :$oid => "5a64d2ce36ab1f1ea4b06228"
>   },
>   :admin => "1234",
>   :users => "12345",
>   :house => {
>     :a => 0,
>     :b => 0,
>     :c => 0
>   },
>    :room => {
>     :a => 0,
>     :b => 2,
>     :c => 1
>   }
> }
> ```

Also note that the [PP class](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/PP.html) for pretty printing is [automatically loaded in Ruby 2.5.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/). In some cases, `pp some_hash` may be all you need. YMMV.